# Source of "undefined" showing in console

Tags: javascript, undefined

Javascript beginner here. This function is supposed to show the position of any given letter in the English alphabet. It seems to run fine, but along with the result, I get an undefined error. Where is this coming from?

```
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

function position(letter){
  letter = letter.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
    if (alphabet[i] === letter){
      console.log('Position in the alphabet is: ' + i);
      break;
    }
  }
};

console.log(position("Z"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
console.log(position("Z"));
```

to:

```
position("Z");
```

Function position does not return anything--that is why you are getting undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You aren't return any values from `position(...)` function. To fix the `undefined` error, you might want to return null if no result is found, like the example:

```
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];


function position(letter){
  letter = letter.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
    if (alphabet[i] === letter){
      return 'Position in the alphabet is: ' + i;
    }
  }

  return null;
};

console.log(position("Z"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `undefined` you are seeing in the console is not an error at all.  Instead, it is the result of the `console.log()` statement in last line of code, as @Russ mentioned. It is logging what it received after executing `position("Z")` - which is actually nothing or `undefined`.

If you wish to be able to use `console.log()` for the output of your function, you could have it `return` a string.  This would also eliminate the need for a `break;` statement in your `for` loop. You might include a "not found" type of default statement as well to protect against an actual error. (@Dorado's `null` default is a good alternative.) Here's what my suggestion might look like for your code:

```
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

function position(letter){
  letter = letter.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
    if (alphabet[i] === letter){
      return('Position in the alphabet is: ' + i);
    }
  }
  return 'Character not found in the alphabet!';
};

console.log(position("Z"));
```

This would give you the single `console` output you desire, remove the `undefined` from your console, and allow you to use this function in other code.

Answer (score 0):

your function could be simply this:

```js
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

function position=(letter)=> {
  console.log(`Position in the alphabet is: ${alphabet.findIndex(el=>el===letter.toLowerCase())}`) 
}

position("Z");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! This sure does look much simpler, but I'm doing this exercise to test my understanding of arrays and loops.

Comment: oh okay then, good luck in your learning. And don't worry it's gonna get much easier with ES6 syntax